# Return/Continue code if yield return does not yield result?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I make the code continue to next steps if the yield return for `WWW class` does not return a value (in case the internet is down)?
Currently the code is stuck at yielding value and does not go ahead.

```
    void Start()
    {
    
    StartCoroutine(GetTimers());
     
    }

    IEnumerator GetTimers()
    {
        WWW data = new WWW("http://TimerWebsiteHosting.com/GetTimers.php");
        yield return data;
        dataString = data.text;

        Items = dataString.Split(';');

        Timer1 = int.Parse(Items[0]);
        Timer2 = int.Parse(Items[1]);
        
    }
```

Comment: does your HTTP API have any kind of timeout/cancellation options?

Comment: You wouldn't use the obsolete `WWW` to begin with ... rather use [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html) and `yield return data.SendWebRequest();` .. then after that you can check for errors `if (data.isNetworkError || data.isHttpError) { ... }`

Comment: @derHugo Could you please give me an example of that class and is there a timeout I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: The [`WWW`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) is by long **obsolete!**

You should rather use a [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html)!

---

You can set a timeout using [`UnityWebRequest.timeout`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-timeout.html)

And then add an error check. On success read out the [`data.downloadHandler.text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.DownloadHandler-text.html)

```
IEnumerator GetTimers()
{
    using(UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("http://TimerWebsiteHosting.com/GetTimers.php"))
    {
        // wait up to one second or whatever you want to use as timeout
        www.timeout = 1;

        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Downlaod failed with {www.responseCode} - {www.error}", this);
            yield break;
        }
        
        dataString = www.downloadHandler.text;
    }

    Items = dataString.Split(';');

    Timer1 = int.Parse(Items[0]);
    Timer2 = int.Parse(Items[1]);
}
```